# Can apply again after UK visa refusal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, application-status

I have a student visa in the UK and wish to apply for a dependent visa for my husband.

He has got a prior refusal under 320(7a) in 2012 for visitor visa. The refusal stated that they weren't satisfied with genuineness of tax papers, which my husband insists were genuine. We didn't apply for appeal because he intended to go for family visit to meet his brother but his brother himself came to Pakistan.

In 2010 too he got this refusal due to bank statement of his brother (sponsor) but after appeal it was successful. He got visit visa and he visited UK for 2 months.

Given this history, can he apply with me. Is there any chance of success and if not then how can he remove this ban now.

Comment: My student visa will be expired in next year.

Answer (score 1):

A refused visa application is not a ban. You can apply again, but unless the conditions that led to the refusal have been addressed you're of course almost certain to be denied again.

And a prior refusal may flag the application for extra scrutiny (just a guess, and the 10 year period may mean such flags have expired by now if they exist). So be extra careful to get all the right boxes ticked and all the correct documents supplied, look extra friendly on the supplied passport photos as well :)

Answer (score 1):

A refusal under paragraph 320 (7A) of the Immigration Rules means any future applications may also be refused under 320 (7B) of the Immigration Rules. A refusal under 320 (7B) attracts an automatic refusal period of up to 10 years https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/307893/GGFR_Sec5v16.0_EXT.pdf

The OP states in a comment that her student visa expires in the next year (2022). IMHO there is minimal chance of a dependent application being approved, probably zero without advice from an Immigration lawyer.

Comment: The provision of the immigration rules cited here [ceased to have effect on December 1st, 2020](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/suitability-false-representations-immigration-staff-guidance).