# Am I banned from the UK for the next 10 years?

Tags: uk, visa-bans

I received my decision today and I am not sure if I am automatically refused entry to the UK for the next 10 years or if I can still apply for a visa in the future.

This was the reason given for the decision:

> In support of your application you have submitted a bank statement for
> account ****; however checks made by this office show that this
> document is not  genuine. As a falsified or non-genuine document has
> been submitted now in relation to your application, it is refused
> under paragraph 9.7.1 of the Immigration Rules. These official
> enquiries have been documented on a Document Verification Report held
> by this office. In view of this I am not satisfied of your intentions
> in wishing to travel to the United Kingdom  now. You should note that
> because this application for entry clearance has been refused under
> paragraph 9.7.2 of the Immigration Rules, any future applications may
> also be refused under paragraph 9.8.1 of the Immigration Rules. A
> refusal under these paragraphs of the Immigration Rules attracts an
> automatic refusal period of up to 10 years. The period starts from the
> date of the previous event in which the deception or submission of
> falsified documents or information was employed.

Comment: What's not clear?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169291/can-apply-again-after-uk-visa-refusal/169782#169782

Comment: @OrganicMarble whether Adam is banned for the next 10 years is not clear.

Comment: The only people who can answer this question authoritatively are the UK authorities.  As written it seems entirely at the discretion of the authorities to decide how long they enforce the punishment.

Answer (score 5):

Your application was refused on deception grounds. That means an automatic 10 year entry ban applies to any *future* application for entry clearance or permission to enter you make within that time period, *starting from the date of the refusal*.

Source: see Overview section, row (f) of https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/974219/Re-entry_Ban_Guidance_v8.00.pdf#page4

Comment: This is not true. The UK has a unique system where the first case of deception carries only the *threat* of a ban. However all future applications will be exceptionally closely scrutinised and unless there are exceptional circumstances will attract a ban.

Comment: @DJClayworth From page9 of the linked document “Where a person has used deception in an application they are subject to a mandatory 10 year re-entry ban - set out in the Suitability: false representations, deception, false documents, nondisclosure of relevant facts guidance, and Paragraph 9.8.4 (d) of the Immigration Rules.”

Comment: I just noticed that the answer I was going to quote contradicting this one is also by you. What's different here? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169291/can-apply-again-after-uk-visa-refusal/169782#169782

Comment: @DJClayworth Nothing. Both answers state that any future application will trigger a 10 year ban. For clarity, I’ve deleted the ‘Yes’ at the start of my answer, if that is the cause of your concern.

Comment: @Traveller That doesn't sound reasonable. Not doubting that you are right, but it sounds unreasonable. A 10 year ban after using forged bank statements seems reasonable. But another application should just be rejected without even looking at it because of the ban, without any other consequences.

Comment: Sorry, read it again: It seems that if you tried to enter with forged documents on Jan 1st 2023, you are not _banned_, but if you apply say in 2030, your application will be rejected automatically and you will be banned until Jan 1st 2033. So you are not "banned", but you cannot enter either.

Comment: @gnasher729 you are correct.  Traveler has misinterpreted the immigration rules.

Comment: @DJClayworth the relevant part of the immigration rules changed in December 2020.  The other answer cites the earlier version of the rules.