# My visit visa was cancelled at the border - am I banned?

Tags: uk, visa-bans

My visit visa was cancelled at the border due to false misrepresentation I was temporarily admitted into UK but I left UK after getting this letter:

> If you fail to comply with bail conditions previously imposed and remain in the United Kingdom, you may have no lawful basis to remain here. By remaining here without lawful basis you may be prosecuted for an offence under the Immigration Act 1971, the penalty for which is a fine of up to £5,000 and / or up to six months imprisonment. You may also face an entry ban of up to ten years. If you decide(s) to stay, then your life in the United Kingdom will become increasingly more difficult. For example, some of the consequences will be that you:
> Will not be allowed to work in the United Kingdom. Immigration
> Enforcement Officers visit workplaces and any employer found to be employing an illegal immigrant may be liable for a civil penalty of up to £20,000 per illegal worker.

> The Immigration Act 2014 will require landlords to conduct immigration checks. Landlords will face a penalty if they let a property to an illegal migrant.

> Will not be allowed to claim benefits. Immigration Enforcement will share your details with HM Revenue & Customs or Department for Work and Pensions. You may be liable for prosecution if you make a false declaration to these organisations or fail to inform them of a change in your circumstances which affects your entitlement to benefits.

> May be charged for any secondary healthcare you receive. 
> Immigration Enforcement may share your details with financial fraud prevention organisations to allow service providers to decide whether you should have access to financial products such as bank accounts and credit agreements.

> Immigration Enforcement will ask the Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency (DVLA) not to issue you with a driving licence. If you already have one, we will ask the DVLA to consider cancelling it. If your licence is cancelled, you will then be unable to drive legally in the United Kingdom.

Did I get a ban? What type of visa can I apply for next time?

Comment: What else does the letter say?  In particular, what conditions were imposed?  What parts of the immigration rules or other ; legal provisions were cited?  Can you post an image of the letter with all identifying information blacked out?

Comment: And why were you admitted temporarily?  What misrepresentation did the officer find?  Was the misrepresentation something you submitted as part of the visa application or was it something you said or showed at the border?

Comment: I was admitted for administrative review which was not successful. Then I was asked to leave. The other letter states what if my circumstances change I must let them know as practically possible in the future. There is no stated  ban on any of the letters I was given. The only condition is that I should leave UK at a stated period. I paid for my flight and left.

Comment: Iam the also canceling your lave to entero remain in accordance with paragraph
9.4 of Appendic V: Immigration Rules for Visitors and you are therefore refused
permission to enter the United Kingdom,

Comment: This another paragraph after administrative review: therefore, conclude that your visa should be cancelled in accordance with paragraph 9.7.3(a) and (b) of part 9 of the immigration rules.

Answer (score 10):

You can apply but you will be refused and at that point a 10 year ban for deception relating to the application described in your question will kick in.

Source: [Re-entry bans](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/974219/Re-entry_Ban_Guidance_v8.00.pdf)

You won’t be going to the UK any time soon.

Comment: The ten year ban is only applicable if there is deception in the subsequent application.

Comment: @phoog No. Deception means an automatic 10 year entry ban applies to any future application for entry clearance or permission to enter made within the time period starting from the date the OP’s visa was cancelled at the border. Ref: Overview section, row (f) of the document linked in the answer. The OP could make a subsequent ‘clean’ application but it would be refused

Comment: @phoog A future application triggers the ban https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178612/am-i-banned-from-the-uk-for-the-next-10-years

Comment: You are misreading the rules.  Future applications must be refused if they are made within ten years if the application in which misrepresentation was used.  See 9.8.1 and 9.8.7: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal  A future application does not trigger a fresh 10-year ban.  And in this case the application was never refused; rather, it was granted and then cancelled.

Comment: Corrections: ...made within ten years of the application...; ...rather, it was granted and then the entry clearance was subsequently cancelled.

Comment: @phoog My answer does not say that a future application triggers a *fresh* 10 year ban. It says that a 10 year ban results from the deceptive application the OP refers to.

Comment: @Traveller your answer says "you will be refused and at that point a 10 year ban ... will kick in" which is easily read as "the ban will last for 10 years from that point"

Comment: @JacobRaihle You quote from my answer but omit the critical part: *”…relating to the application described in your question”.

Comment: My reading of the letter posted: "If you _fail to comply with bail conditions_ previously imposed and remain in the United Kingdom... You _may_ also face an entry ban of up to ten years". I'm betting this is how the OP read it and that's why he's confused. You're saying that despite the "if" and "may", he's got a 10 year ban without question?

Comment: @FreeMan I think UK has a policy of issuing an automatic 10 year ban for fraudulent applications. It used to be the case that it could be flexible as to whether it was applied, but now it is automatic. All future applications will be rejected on the basis of this ban.